# Are the rationals homeomorphic to any power of the rationals?

Tags: gn.general-topology

I asked myself, which spaces have the property that $X^2$ is homeomorphic to $X$. I started to look at some examples like $\mathbb{N}^2 \cong \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}^2\ncong \mathbb{R}, C^2\cong C$ (for the cantor set $C$). And then I got stuck, when I considered the rationals. So the question is:

Is $\mathbb{Q}^2$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes, Sierpinski proved that every countable metric
space without isolated points is homeomorphic to the rationals:
http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm .

An amusing consequence of Sierpinski's theorem is that
$\mathbb{Q}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. Of course here one
$\mathbb{Q}$ has the order topology, and the other has the $p$-adic
topology (for your favourite prime $p$) :-)

Answer (score 20):

As Gerald Edgar points out in his comment on Xandi Tuni's answer, the continued fraction trick works for the **ir**rationals, not for the rationals.  But this turns out to be enough:

1) An irrational number has a unique continued fraction expansion.  Therefore the irrationals are isomorphic to an infinite direct product of ${\mathbb Z}$ with itself.  Therefore (writing ${\mathbb I}$ for the irrationals) we have ${\mathbb I}={\mathbb I}^2$.

2)  Therefore ${\mathbb I}^2$ imbeds as a dense subset of the reals.  Now map ${\mathbb Q}\times {\mathbb Q}$ to ${\mathbb I}\times {\mathbb I}$ by (say) adding $\sqrt{2}$ to each component.  This imbeds ${\mathbb Q}\times {\mathbb Q}$ as a countable dense subset of the reals.

3)  Now use the fact that every countable dense subset of the reals is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb Q}$.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, they are homeomorphic. To construct a homeomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q^2$, one can proceed roughly as follows: express $q\in \mathbb Q$ as a continued fraction $[a_0, a_1,a_2,...]$ (of finite length) and associate with it the pair $([a_0,a_2,...], [a_1,a_3,...])$.

Mind that this is a homeomorphism, but not an isometry (cf comment on Tom's answer).

I vaguely remember that there is a general Theorem in point set topology stating that all countable topological spaces "of the same kind as $\mathbb Q$" are homeomorphic.

Comment: Why the construction does not work for $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: My vague memory is Sierpinskis theorem cited by Robin.

Comment: @Wadim: The map still exists over the reals, but it is not a homeomorphism (The continued fractions will be infinite, and that kills continuity).

Comment: Each positive rational has two different continued fraction expansions. 5+1/2 = [5,2] maps to ([5],[2]) = (5,2).  But 5+1/2 = [5,1,1] also, which maps to ([5,1],[1]) = (6,1).

Comment: @Xandi:  On the contrary, it works with infinite continued fractions to show that the space of irrationals is homeomorphic to its square.


Comment: So, how to struggle against the double representation of rationals? (There should be a trick: what about taking the even length only? BTW, (6,1) is also represented by [6,1]...)

Comment: Sry but i was wondering why this is 
- surjective: only $a_0$ might be negative; hence you never get $a_1$ negative and hence the map is not surjective.
- continuous : Note that $a_n:=[1;n]=1+1/n$ converges to $1$, but $([1],[n])=(1,n)$ diverges.
I don't know how to repair this.  Still it would be nice to have an explicit homeomorphism.

Comment: You are right, there should be an additional trick to make the argument work... I'm out of wisdom for the moment.

Comment: There is no way to make this work for rationals.  (That's a strong statement.)  It is fine for irrationals, however.

Comment: The irrationals have a nice characterisation as well (the rationals are the unique countable metric space without isolated points): the irrationals are the unique 0-dimensional [base of clopen sets] separable metric space that is nowhere locally compact [no non-empty open set has compact closure]. It is a way of showing that the irrationals are homeomorphic to N^N and hence to any finite or countable power of itself. 

Comment: @HenrikRüping maybe constraining the sign to match or not match the parity is the trick to make it work?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar how definite is your statement this can't work for rationals? I wasn't sure if that was meant as "I'd bet my bottom dollar there's no trick to make it work" or "I know a complicated reason that proves it can't work which is too long to state here".

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so: the completion of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that a homeomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^2\to\mathbb{Q}$ would give a homeomorphism  $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Your argument only shows that there is no isometry.

Comment: You're quite right. I thought it sounded too good to be true...

Comment: This will give a really good exercise for a topology course!

Comment: It also shows there is no homeomorphism uniformly continuous in both directions.