# Nonhomeomorphic CW-complexes that are "stably" homeomorphic

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Do there exist CW-complexes $X$ and $Y$ that are not homeomorphic, but $X \times I$ and $Y \times I$ are homeomorphic?  Here $I$ denotes the unit interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Take $X$ a punctured torus ($T^2\setminus$open disk) and $Y$ a three-punctured $S^2$.
Then $X\times I=Y\times I$ is a genus 2 handlebody.