# Homeomorphisms and disjoint unions

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Assume that $X \sqcup X \cong Y \sqcup Y$ (here $X \sqcup X$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $X$, considered as a topological space, and similarly for $Y \sqcup Y$).  Then I'm pretty sure that we must have $X \cong Y$.  This clearly holds if $X$ and $Y$ are connected, but I can't seem to prove it in general.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see a proof.  I do see a counterexample which involves four copies of [0,1) , but that is not compact.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.06.08

Comment: Scratch that.  My counterexample is not, and I am unsure that it could be massaged into one.  Gerhard "Back To Your Regular Programming" Paseman, 2013.06.08

Comment: If only you hadn't required the spaces to live in $\mathbb R^n$, I could simply cite my answer to an earlier question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26414 .  But with the restriction to subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, all I can say is "interesting question".

Comment: @Andreas Your example seems to work if you do not assume $n<\omega$. ;)

Comment: @Andreas Blass : Yes, I was aware that there were counterexamples if you allowed sufficiently weird spaces (the sorts of spaces that show up in my nightmares; I try not to think about them).

Comment: Since one of the spaces that Andy Putman referred to has a lot of legs and shows up in nightmares I think it is safe to call this space a monster!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The result you want is *false*.  Counterexamples are given in

Yamamoto, Shuji and Yamashita, Atsushi,
A counterexample related to topological sums. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 134 (2006), no. 12, 3715–3719.

These counterexamples are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: The authors also mention that one can modify their construction to obtain an example in $\mathbb R^2$. 

Comment: Beautiful!!!!!!

Comment: Beautiful indeed.