# Question about product topology

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, tag-removed, descriptive-set-theory

Suppose $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is dense without interior point, and for every open interval $I,J\subset\mathbb{R}$, $I\cap S$ is homeomorphic to $J\cap S$.

Is $S\times S$ homeomorphic to $S$?

By Luzin scheme,  if $S$ is the set of rationals or irationals , I can see this statement is true.

Comment: Dear @user35739, your question is probably better suited at http://math.stackexchange.com/, see the FAQ of this site.

Comment: @Andras: would you explain why?

Comment: @user35739: I would first of all wonder about a full characterization of the spaces $S$ with the property of having all (relative) open intervals homeomorphic one to another. There is no need  a priori to mention anything about $S$ being dense or having empty interior (it's that elegant :-).

Comment: The question seems to be well within the scope of MO, compare http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26001/are-the-rationals-homeomorphic-to-any-power-of-the-rationals with an answer containing a reference to several proofs of Sierpinsky's theorem, that provides a partial answer to the OP question.

Comment: Also, for every $G_{\delta}$-subset $S$ of ${\mathbb R}$ which is dense and has empty interior, one has $S\cong S\times S$. The reason is that such $S$ is a Polish space and, hence, Alexandrov-Uryson theorem implies that both $S$ and $S\times S$ are homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}\setminus {\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: I wonder if this question is related to the continuum hypothesis. What about sets $S$ which have an intermediate cardinality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-08/S0002-9939-96-03561-7/S0002-9939-96-03561-7.pdf), van Engelen constructs a strongly homogeneous, zero dimensional, Borel, dense subspace $Y$ of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that while $Y$ does not admit a topological group structure, $Y^2$ does. I haven't read the proof but maybe you can use it to construct a counterexample in the context of $\mathbb{R}$?