# Continuous Functions

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a pair of continuous surjective functions say $f_1$ and $f_2$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself such that for every $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f_1^{-1}(x) \cap f_2^{-1}(y)$ is non-empty?

Comment: I guess that this question would better suited for math.stackexchange.com rather than MO.

Comment: what is the topology?

Comment: Marc, the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ is derived from $\mathbb{R}$ and the one on $\mathbb{Q}^2$, is the topology derived from $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @MarcPalm I presume its metric topology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the two projections from ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}$ to ${\mathbb Q}$ and use the [fact](https://mathoverflow.net/a/148680/10503) that ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb Q}$.