# On homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with non-homeomorphic complements

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $A,B$ be two homeomorphic topological subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that their complements $\mathbb{R}^3 - A, \mathbb{R}^3 - B$ are not homeomorphic to each other.  Must $A \cong B$ contain a homeomorphic image of the Cantor set?

(It is known that there are homeomorphic images $A,B$ of the Cantor set such that $\mathbb{R}^3 - A, \mathbb{R}^3 - B$ are not homeomorphic, see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686418690060X)

---

UPDATE 1:

The answer is no, as Wojowu's answer shows. This leads to
**Question 2:** Must $A \cong B$ contain a homeomorphic image of $\mathbb{Q}$?

---

UPDATE 2:

After Wojowu's answer, the interesting question remaining is

**Question 3:** Let $A,B$ be two closed, countable, topological subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ homeomorphic to each other. Must  their complements $\mathbb{R}^3 - A, \mathbb{R}^3 - B$ be homeomorphic to each other?

Comment: If your first question is answered satisfactorily, it would be nicer to accept the answer and post new questions, if such should arise, separately.

Comment: I did, the new question is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423898/do-any-two-closed-countable-homeomorphic-subsets-of-mathbbr3-have-homeom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb Q^3$ and $B=\{0\}\times\mathbb Q^2$. It is a [classical result](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26001/30186) that they are homeomorphic (both homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$), and their complements are not homeomorphic as $\mathbb R^3-B$ contains a subset homeomorphic to an open ball, while $\mathbb R^3-A$ doesn't (e.g. by the invariance of domain theorem).

However, since $A,B$ are countable, they don't contain a copy of the Cantor set.

---

The answer to the new question is also negative. Indeed let $A=\{(0,0,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $B=\{(0,0,1/n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. Both of these are discrete and countable, so are homeomorphic. On the other hand, the complement of $A$ is a manifold, while $(0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb R^3-B$ has no Euclidean neighbourhood.

Comment: @bof It should be, yeah - in $\mathbb R^3-A$ and $\mathbb R^3-B$ you can consider the subsets of points which have a Euclidean neighbourhood, and see that those will not be homeomorphic.

Comment: @bof : good question, I'm editing the main question to include it.

Comment: @bof : there are advantages and disadvantages to the two options, and you may be right that it is better to start a new question. I'll wait a couple of days to see if there is a quick answer, and if not I could accept the answer and start a new post. An advantage of my approach is that we have all the discussion in one place...

Comment: @bof The answer is still negative, see updated answer.

Comment: @Wojowu: that's another good example, thanks! What if we require that both $A,B$ be closed subspaces?

Comment: ... under which assumption we could again ask if $A\cong B$ must contain a Cantor set.

Comment: If $A,B$ are closed we can suppose they are countable, because if not, they contain perfect sets (their sets of condensation points) which in turn contain Cantor sets

Comment: Perhaps an induction on [Cantor Bendixon rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)#Cantor.E2.80.93Bendixson_rank) could work to prove that if $A,B\subseteq R^3$ are closed and countable (so they are dispersed and have countable Cantor-Bendixon rank) and $A$ is homeomorphic to $B$, then $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B$.